# Python 3 многомерный словарь

Tags: python, python-3.x

Изучая python 3.x , прошёл курсы по основам. До этого писал на php.

Сейчас решил выполнить задуманную задачу:

1. Прочитать csv
2. По мере чтения строк файла, обрабатывать их и записывать в массив, создавая нужную структуру
3. ...

Вот мой код

```
import csv


def gene_name(gene, polfzm, genotype):
    return '_'.join([gene, polfzm, genotype]).strip().replace(" ", "-")


data = {}
genes = []

with open('example-2.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file, delimiter=';')
    for row in reader:
        group = row['group']
        person_id = row['person_id']
        ab = row['genotype']
        name = gene_name(row['gene_name'], row['polfzm_name'], ab)

        data[group][person_id][name] = ab  # Возникает ошибка
```

И тут проблема. Если я правильно понимаю, то для хранения моих данных в структурированном виде подходит Словрь - `data`. В php я мог легко создать нужную мне структуру/вложенность `data[group][person_id][name] = ab`. Тут же возникает ошибка `KeyError: '3'`

В чём ошибка моего подхода. На курсах, что я проходил, не работали с многомерными структурами. Правильно ли я выбрал тип переменной для хранения данных - Словарь? Как верно тут поступить?

Структура данных, которую требуется получить

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример данных csv

```
person_id;number;gene_name;polfzm_name;genotype;expr1;group
1086;AT1;F11;T/C rs2036914;CC;БеремПлохо;3
1086;AT1;F11;С/T rs2289252;TT;БеремПлохо;3
1086;AT1;ITGA2;C/T rs1126643;CT;БеремПлохо;3
1086;AT1;ITGB3;T/C rs5918;CC;БеремПлохо;3
1086;AT1;VEGF;C/T rs3025039;CC;БеремПлохо;3
1085;AT2;F11;T/C rs2036914;TT;БеремПлохо;3
1085;AT2;F11;С/T rs2289252;CC;БеремПлохо;3
1085;AT2;ITGA2;C/T rs1126643;TT;БеремПлохо;3
1085;AT2;ITGB3;T/C rs5918;TT;БеремПлохо;3
1085;AT2;VEGF;C/T rs3025039;CC;БеремПлохо;3
23;МИД6;ACE;Alu Ins/Del;ID;БеремНорм;1
23;МИД6;F1;Thr312Ala;ThrThr;БеремНорм;1
23;МИД6;F11;T/C rs2036914;TC;БеремНорм;1
23;МИД6;F11;С/T rs2289252;CT;БеремНорм;1
23;МИД6;F13;Val34Leu;ValLeu;БеремНорм;1
23;МИД6;F2;G20210А;GG;БеремНорм;1
23;МИД6;F5;Arg506Gln;GG;БеремНорм;1
23;МИД6;ITGA2;C/T rs1126643;CC;БеремНорм;1
23;МИД6;ITGB3;T/C rs5918;TC;БеремНорм;1
23;МИД6;VEGF;G-634C;GG;БеремНорм;1
```

Данные - плоская выборка данных из реляционной БД. Т.к. там были связи, а данные выбирались из нескольких таблиц, многие значения от строчки к строчке повторяются. Например, первые 5 строк данных (не учитывая шапку) - относятся к одному человеку (person_id), одной группе (group), но имеют разные гены (gene_name) и т.п.

По данным планируется делать множественные сравнения, поиск комбинаций и т.п. - порядка ~ 4 млн проходов, поэтому нужна такая структура, чтобы не бегать по всем строчкам csv впустую столько раз

Comment: Может правильно, а может и нет. Обозначьте в вопросе, как вы представляете себе словарь data заполненный данными

Comment: data[group] = dict([(person_id, dict([(name, ab)]))])

Comment: @Glebium, тогда старое значение в `data[group]` будет каждый раз перезаписываться

Comment: @insolor, исходил из того, что на каждой итерации цикла значение переменной group не повторяется. Если повторяются, тогда никакого другого решения я не вижу, кроме как проверять: if group in data: ... else: ...

Comment: @Glebium в ответе я показал как можно сделать.

Comment: @insolor, интересное решение. Никогда не пользовался defaultdict. Как-нибудь почитаю про это.

Comment: @Эникейщик дополнил свой вопрос

Comment: @Glebium подтверждаю `data[group] = dict([(person_id, dict([(name, ab)]))])` в результате остаются только последние строки, старые перезаписываются.

Comment: Добавил еще пару вариантов в ответ.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Изначально словарь у вас пустой. При запросе данных по любому ключу из пустого словаря будет возникать исключение `KeyError`. В данном случае можно использовать `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

# Словарь, в котором значение по умолчанию другой словарь,
#  у которого значение по умолчанию обычный словарь
data = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict))

group = 'group'
person_id = '3'
name = 'John Smith'

ab = 'ab'

data[group][person_id][name] = ab

print(data[group][person_id][name])  # Выведет ab
```

Полный код:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint


def gene_name(gene, polfzm, genotype):
    return '_'.join([gene, polfzm, genotype]).strip().replace(" ", "-")


data = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict))
genes = []

with open('example-2.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file, delimiter=';')
    for row in reader:
        group = row['group']
        person_id = row['person_id']
        ab = row['genotype']
        name = gene_name(row['gene_name'], row['polfzm_name'], ab)

        data[group][person_id][name] = ab


pprint(data)
```

Вывод на примере ваших данных:

```
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x7f73a7732ee0>,
            {'1': defaultdict(<class 'dict'>,
                              {'23': {'ACE_Alu-Ins/Del_ID': 'ID',
                                      'F11_T/C-rs2036914_TC': 'TC',
                                      'F11_С/T-rs2289252_CT': 'CT',
                                      'F13_Val34Leu_ValLeu': 'ValLeu',
                                      'F1_Thr312Ala_ThrThr': 'ThrThr',
                                      'F2_G20210А_GG': 'GG',
                                      'F5_Arg506Gln_GG': 'GG',
                                      'ITGA2_C/T-rs1126643_CC': 'CC',
                                      'ITGB3_T/C-rs5918_TC': 'TC',
                                      'VEGF_G-634C_GG': 'GG'}}),
             '3': defaultdict(<class 'dict'>,
                              {'1085': {'F11_T/C-rs2036914_TT': 'TT',
                                        'F11_С/T-rs2289252_CC': 'CC',
                                        'ITGA2_C/T-rs1126643_TT': 'TT',
                                        'ITGB3_T/C-rs5918_TT': 'TT',
                                        'VEGF_C/T-rs3025039_CC': 'CC'},
                               '1086': {'F11_T/C-rs2036914_CC': 'CC',
                                        'F11_С/T-rs2289252_TT': 'TT',
                                        'ITGA2_C/T-rs1126643_CT': 'CT',
                                        'ITGB3_T/C-rs5918_CC': 'CC',
                                        'VEGF_C/T-rs3025039_CC': 'CC'}})})
```

`defaultdict` - это тот же самый словарь по сути, работает точно так же (ну, кроме создания значения по умолчанию при запросе отсутствующего ключа). Под описанную вами задачу подходит, только при выводе через `print` отображается по-другому.

Для вывода в более привычном виде можно сериализовывать в json например:

```
import json
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False))
```

---

Вариант решения без `defaultdict`:

```
import csv
from pprint import pprint


def gene_name(gene, polfzm, genotype):
    return '_'.join([gene, polfzm, genotype]).strip().replace(" ", "-")


data = dict()
genes = []

with open('example-2.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file, delimiter=';')
    for row in reader:
        group = row['group']
        person_id = row['person_id']
        ab = row['genotype']
        name = gene_name(row['gene_name'], row['polfzm_name'], ab)
        
        if group not in data:
            data[group] = dict()
            data[group][person_id] = dict()  # микрооптимизация
        elif person_id not in data[group]:
            data[group][person_id] = dict()
        
        data[group][person_id][name] = ab


pprint(data)
```

В итоге получается обычный словарь.

---

И еще один вариант, со своим классом вместо `defaultdict`, неограниченной вложенностью словарей и поддержкой `pickle` (правда без поддержки сериализации в json):

```
from collections import UserDict


class NestedDict(UserDict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key not in self.data:
            self.data[key] = NestedDict()
        
        return self.data[key]


d = NestedDict()

d['Lorem']['ipsum']['dolor']['sit']['amet']['consectetur']['adipiscing']['elit'] = 1

print(d)
print(type(d))

import pickle

p = pickle.dumps(d)
d1 = pickle.loads(p)
print(d1)
```

```
{'Lorem': {'ipsum': {'dolor': {'sit': {'amet': {'consectetur': {'adipiscing': {'elit': 1}}}}}}}}
<class '__main__.NestedDict'>
{'Lorem': {'ipsum': {'dolor': {'sit': {'amet': {'consectetur': {'adipiscing': {'elit': 1}}}}}}}}
```

Comment: `print(data[group])` выводит `defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'3': {'John Smith': 'ab'}})`, а не просто структуру данных

Comment: Ну так это и не просто структура данных. Так и должно выводить.

Comment: Если нужен словарь, выводите `print(dict(data[group]))`

Comment: Спасибо большое. Вроде бы работает) Посмотрим, как дальше пойдёт

Answer (score 2):

Есть более простой способ, чем описывает @insolor

```
data = dict()
data.setdefault(group, dict()).setdefault(person_id, dict())[name] = ab
```

Как указано в комментарии к методу `setdefault`

> Insert key with a value of default if key is not in the dictionary.
> Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default.

Comment: Недостаток этого метода, что каждый раз при обращении к setdefault будет создаваться dict() из его аргумента, и в случае если такой ключ уже есть это создание будет просто отнимать время без несения полезной нагрузки. Если таких вызовов будет десятки тысяч и более, это будет довольно медленнее и заметно.

Comment: @vadimvaduxa а есть ли ещё какие-нибудь подходы? С лямбдой много проблем

Comment: @vadimvaduxa проверил на домашнем ноутбуке - выигрыш на 1млн интераций порядка 30-50 секунд. Боевая выборка - 47 млн. Удастся сэкономить около 40 минут.

Comment: Я добавил в свой ответ вариант без defaultdict, время работы не замерял.

Comment: Вообще, это неплохой вариант, хотя на мой вкус довольно громоздко выглядит. В моем варианте только инициализация defaultdict громоздкая, а добавление данных в словарь простое, в вашем ответе наоборот - добавление данных в цикле громоздкое. Создание пустых словарей в цикле конечно не очень хорошо, но видимо их удаление (или переиспользование?) как-то оптимизировано, раз уж работает быстрее чем `defaultdict`.

Comment: @insolor нет-нет defaultdict работает быстрее, возможно я не так выразился в комментарии выше. defaultdict с лямбдой значительно быстрее, чем setdefault() и создание каждый раз словарей пустых.

Comment: @n.osennij тогда можно посмотреть 2 и 3 вариант в моем ответе. Последний наиболее удобный (на мой взгляд), но возможно будет медленнее, чем через defaultdict.