# Python 3 ошибка с lambda во вложенных словарях при использовании multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

Возникла необходимость разделить большую работу на куски и отдать на выполнение каждому ядру процессора, а после результаты собрать и объединить в один общий. Прочитал [статью](https://urban-institute.medium.com/using-multiprocessing-to-make-python-code-faster-23ea5ef996ba), вдохновился и ... подавился.

Вот мой код, который работает

```
import concurrent.futures
from collections import defaultdict

data = []


def prepare_data():
    data.append(1)
    data.append(2)
    data.append(3)


def do_work(my_data):
    combination_frequency = []
    for i in my_data:
        total = 0
        for k in range(2000):
            total += k**k
        combination_frequency = i+1
    return combination_frequency


if __name__ == '__main__':

    prepare_data()

    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        cores = 2
        results = [executor.submit(do_work, data) for _ in range(cores)]

    all_results = []
    for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(results):
        all_results.append(f.result())

    print(all_results)
```

Простенькая функция `do_work`, которая получает какие-то данные для работы и возвращает потом результат. Ниже я как будто бы отдаю какой-то кусок работы на отдельное ядро и запускаю работу. В конце получаю все результаты и объединяю их. В примере выше всё работает. Однако если я попробую вернуть многомерный словарь, возникает ошибка - `AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'do_work.<locals>.<lambda>'`

```
import concurrent.futures
from collections import defaultdict

data = []


def prepare_data():
    data.append(1)
    data.append(2)
    data.append(3)


def do_work(my_data):
    combination_frequency = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
    for i in my_data:
        total = 0
        for k in range(2000):
            total += k**k
        combination_frequency['s']['bb'] = i+1
    return combination_frequency


if __name__ == '__main__':

    prepare_data()

    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        cores = 2
        results = [executor.submit(do_work, data) for _ in range(cores)]

    all_results = []
    for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(results):
        all_results.append(f.result())

    print(all_results)
```

Почему мне нужны многомерные словари - в моём [предыдущем вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1239440/python-3-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C#1239462).

Как быть? Что можно сделать?

Comment: А зачем вообще словарь, если у вас всегда по одним и тем же ключам данные записываются? Или это для примера?

Comment: @insolor тут для примера, конечно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка связана с особенностью pickle относительно lambdа - он передает имя а не тело функции и потом пытается ее импортировать по имени при десереализации, при сборе результатов соответсвенно ее не находит так как lambdа не имеет имени

простое решение - вынести логику lambdа в отдельную обычную функцию с именем, например так:

```
def def_dict_factory():
    return defaultdict(list)

def do_work(my_data):
    combination_frequency = defaultdict(def_dict_factory)
    ...
```

Так же посмотрите на [этот вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25348532/can-python-pickle-lambda-functions)

Comment: а как быть с отправкой в эту функцию аргумента такой структуры - `defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))`? Если отправляю - `Can't pickle <function <lambda> at 0x000001FDD1CD9700>: attribute lookup <lambda> on __main__ failed`.

Comment: @n.osennij, Не могли бы Вы уточнить Ваш вопрос ? В какую функцию Вы хотите передать lambda ?

Comment: do_work(сюда). Но я разобрался. Сделал при инициализации переменной то, что вы предложили в ответе.

Comment: Но честно скажу, это какая-то жесть. Неимоверно сложно работать со структурами данных... Чтобы получить несчастный многомерный словарь (ассоциативный массив по сути) нужно танцевать с бубном и писать какую-то дичь

Comment: Если Вам действительно надо какие-то сложные структуры данных то посмотрите на библиотеки, например NumPy, Pandas
Возможно они смогут облегчить Вашу задачу.
Или возможно есть другой способ организовать Ваши данные для удобной работы с ними

Comment: @Tr1nks ни одна из них не позволяет создавать вложенные ассоциативные словари. В моём предыдущем вопросе (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1239440/python-3-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C#1239462) предлагалось `data[group] = dict([(person_id, dict([(name, ab)]))])`, но если добавлять в цикле по такой структуре данные, предыдущие будут перезаписываться. нужны дополнительные проверки. Всё это отвратительно. Дёрнул меня чёрт связаться с python...

Comment: @Teretto Работайте с json, в нём можно какие угодно структуры хранить. А вообще непонятно в чём проблема. Словари могут быть какой угодно вложенности. Основная сложность у вас это плоские `csv` перевести во вложенные структуры, ну так это в любом языке проблема будет и ещё бОльшая чем в питоне.

Comment: @CrazyElf в php это не проблема. Завожу массив и просто в него добавляю данные, как хочу. Есть у меня массив, например, arr1. И я к нему `arr1['some']['some2']['name1'] = 555`, а потом `arr1['some']['some2']['NAME2'] = 777` - и всё работает, данные не перезатираются, создаётся автоматически структура.

Comment: @CrazyElf Если работать с JSON, и пытаться туда что-то записать, мне же придётся постоянно считывать данные и записывать обратно на каждом цикле ~ 4.000.000 раз